# How does the SE Bot pick questions to tweet?

Tags: support

One of my questions was recently [tweeted](https://music.stackexchange.com/posts/31381/revisions) by the SE Bot.

How does StackBot pick questions to tweet? Its not the first time one of my questions was tweeted and I'm curious what the criteria ar.